# Do I need to declare both nationalities when travelling to the U.S.?

Tags: esta, dual-nationality

I have a Swiss and German passport and want to travel to the U.S. but only with my Swiss passport. Do I need to declare the German nationality in the ESTA application? And if so, would I need to take the German passport with me to the U.S.?

Answer (score 13):

Nope. You use the one you intend to travel with/as.

Eg, I have dual NZ and South African citizenship. The South African passport is awful to travel on, and I can get ESTA for the US. So I apply for the ESTA, and travel, using my NZ passport.  I've done this regularly.

[From the US ESTA page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1096/~/esta---eligible-passport,-country-of-issuance,-citizenship):

> If you have dual citizenship and have registered with ESTA, you should
>   use your VWP-eligible passport to board the plane when you leave your
>   country of departure and when you arrive in the U.S. If both your
>   countries of citizenship are VWP-eligible, then we strongly recommend
>   you choose which one you want to claim for purposes of travel to the
>   U.S., and use that country's passport each time you travel. One person
>   with two different ESTA authorizations creates confusion that will
>   only delay your travel.

Comment: But, the last time you applied for ESTA, did it include the question about other citizenships?  Now that they ask, it seems irresponsible to advise someone to withhold that information.

Comment: @phoog I was referencing the passport he/she is travelling with.  Obviously any forms that ask a specific question should be answered truthfully.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely declare both nationalities on the ESTA form, but you only Need to bring the passport the ESTA is tied to